# How to use Onsen-UI 2 beta and Angular2 in Monaca?

Tags: cordova, angular, onsen-ui, monaca

how can I setup a Monaca Project to use Onsen-UI 2 AND Angular2? I tried the following: Config -> Manage JS/CSS Components... When I search for Angular2 the do actually see angular2. However, the available versions don't contain 2.x, right now 1.5r1 is the highest available version. Am I missing something or is it just not possible right now? And if not, does anyone have a good guide so setup a PhoneGap + Angular2 + Onsen UI 2 environment?

Comment: You might get help in here: https://community.onsen.io/